# Is Passing Intent Extras Between Activities Bad Style?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, encapsulation

It seems to me that passing extras via Intent calls is a violation of encapsulation, since classes are directly communicating with one another. That being said, the only viable alternative to this that I have found is setting a variable in some shared class and just having each activity pull data from it - part of me, however, can't help feeling that this isn't a great design choice either. Can someone shed some light on this?

Comment: It's actually analogous to `SomeClass myClass = new SomeClass("Some data");`. The difference is that the `Activity` class in Android is a special case and can't be instantiated using `new` nor should any method be made publicly available to any other application component. Passing data in an `Intent` is a core part of the Android model.

Comment: It's actually the opposite: putting something in a shared data structure and then updating it across activities is the antipattern!  In this regard, Android activities should try to be pretty stateless.  (With the shared state being stored in persistent places via content providers and shared prefs.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encapsulation, as one of the whale of Object-Oriented paradigm, assumes that you free programmers, who will use your class in future, from the necessity to know how does your component built inside and what complex aspects does it hold, carrying out this information to comfortable and clear programming interface (in the best cases).

`Intent` model was developed so, that it assumes interaction between main components of operating system, especially `Activity`s, and also it assumes that you need to accompany your intents with some concrete information such as kind of `ACTION`s you want to perform, a `CATEGORY` of your intent and some set of `DATA` that need to implement your intents. So this is convenient model in such kind of interactions.

At the same time, using some shared class between activities when there is a ready solution for that, is rather irrelevant approach, IMO.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't, you'll end up needing it. Usually I pass minimum info between activities and then check out big data in the launched activity's onCreate().